Is any Schwartz function a Fourier multiplier?
If $m$ is a Schwartz function then $m=\widehat{n}$ for another $n$ Schwartz function because, fourier transform is an isomorphism between the Schwartz space.
Now, the operator $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi) \widehat{u}(\xi))=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\widehat{n}(\xi)\widehat{u}(\xi))=n*u$ (convolution theorem). Then, $\left\|n * u\right\|_{p}\leq \left\|n\right\|_1\left\|u\right\|_p$ Young's inequality. Therefore, $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $1<p<\infty$.
What is wrong?

What is bothering you about this statement?

Schwartz $\Rightarrow$ Fourier multiplier?

I am able to read. Why do you doubt that this is true? You have given a proof.
